# How to run tests on many machines in parallel

Tags: c#, selenium, cmd, selenium-grid

I use MSTEST and write tests in c#.
I have some tests in my project at a test class.
I have test settings file with: `parallelTestCount='0'`

There is a selenium grid hub installed on my machine.

There is a node installed on my machine and there is another node installed on another machine.

I run the test from cmd as:

```
MSTest.exe /testcontainr:C:/MyProject.dll /testsettings:C:MyParallelSettings.testsettings
```

Then some tests start running in parallel at one node on one machine. But only after the tests end running, the other tests start running at the other node on the second machine in parallel.

How can I run all the test run in parallel on some other machines at the same time?

Comment: Using PowerShell `Invoke-Command` will let you specify many machines to run on concurrently. You can also get the output individually.

Comment: Can you give me an example how to use PowerShell Invoke-Command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `start` will launch each executable within split seconds from each other, without the one having to wait for the other to complete, so simply run the commands in batch:

```
start "" "MSTest.exe" /testcontainr:C:/MyProject.dll /testsettings:C:MyParallelSettings.testsettings
start "" "MSTest.exe" etc.
start "" "MSTest.exe" etc...
```